# Does SO still use DotNetOpenAuth as a component in it's authentication?

Tags: discussion, dotnetopenauth

I was thumbing through some of the sites listed on : http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/case-studies/

Although the dotnetopenauth website claims that the sites use dotnetopenauth, I found many of them used a traditional login/registration process and I could find no evidence of an openid Relying party signin process.

I assume, at one time, these sites were actually using dotnetopenauth, and for one reason or other switch away from it.

StackOverflow is the first site on the list, and I know that I can still login to SO using my OpenID credentials. Is SO using DotNetOpenAuth, or are you using some other code base?

Comment: Is there an automated way to move it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. StackOverflow still uses DotNetOpenAuth.